# want to create multidimentional array to read array and its related options in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sqlite, multidimensional-array

i want to create a multidimentional array in javascript where i want to fetch question and its related options in a an array

```
demoArray[i] = new Array();
var id=results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id;
demoArray[i]["question"] = results.rows.item(i).question;
demoArray[i]["id"] = results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id;

tx.executeSql('SELECT option,value,del_opt_id FROM delta_option WHERE del_ques_id='+results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id+' order by value desc', [], getOptionDetails, errorCB);

function getOptionDetails(tx,results){
    console.log("option query");
    var lent = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + lent + " rows found.");
    for(var j=0;j<lent;j++){
        demoArray[i]=new Array();
        demoArray[i]["option"]=results.rows.item(j).option;
        }
}
```

my query is how should i create an array for option in this same demoArray

```
1{
ques:question_string;
id:question_id;
option:{
    option_name:option_string;
    option_id:option_id_string;
   }

 }
2{
 ..
 ..
 } and so on
```

This should be my array structure 
how to code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var questionArray = [];
 var questionCounter = 0;
 var optionsArray = [];

 function getQuestionDetails(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       //console.log(results.rows.item(i).question);
       questionCounter = i;
       questionArray[i] = new Array();
       //var id = results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id;
       questionArray[i]["question"] = results.rows.item(i).question;
       questionArray[i]["id"] = results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id;
       tx.executeSql('SELECT option,value,del_opt_id FROM delta_option WHERE del_ques_id='+results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id+' order by value desc', [], getOptionDetails, errorCB);
      // console.log(questionArray[i]["question"]); 
    } //EOC for
 } //EOC question function

 function getOptionDetails(tx,results){
   console.log(questionArray[questionCounter]["question"])
   var optLength = results.rows.length;
   var qOptions = questionArray[questionCounter]["qOptions"] = [];
   for(var j=0;j<optLength;j++){
      qOptions[j] = [];
      qOptions[j]['optionId'] = results.rows.item(j).del_opt_id;
      qOptions[j]['option'] = results.rows.item(j).option;
      qOptions[j]['optionValue'] = results.rows.item(j).value;
   } //EOC for
   console.log(questionArray[0]["qOptions"][0]["optionId"]);

   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.quesData=questionArray; 
   });
 //console.log(qOptions["option"])
} //EOC function
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
var demoArray = [];
var ques = results.rows.item(i).question;
var id = results.rows.item(i).del_ques_id;
var quesObj = {};

var options = [];
var option = {};
//call your query and fill the options. I am assuming that you have multiple options for a question, Loop the next three lines of code for all the options of a particular question
option["option_name"] = "Some name result from your query";
option["option_id"] = "Some id result from your query";
//push this to your options
options.push(option);

//now create the quesObj consisting of ques,id and options
quesObj["question"] = ques;
quesObj["id"] = id;
quesObj["option"] = options;

//now add your quesObj to the demoArray
demoArray.push(quesObj);
```

Now you can loop the entire code above to add multiple questions to your demoArray.

The result would be something like:

```
[
{
    question:question_string;
    id:question_id;
    option:[
        {
            option_name:option_string;
            option_id:option_id_string;
        },
        {
            option_name:option_string;
            option_id:option_id_string;
        }
        ....
 }
 {
        ..... Other Question Objects 
        ......
 } and so on
```

]

Comment: i creates object but it doesnt provide me this multiarray